# As you get further in difficulties will Diablo/evils change color?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm just curious will they ever change color like in D2, I always though that was a pretty cool addition to show the difficulty, and with the graphical changes it would be kinda cool to see a blue/purple diablo in d3 so I was curious if they would ever change color in this one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, they don't - though there's already the Phase 2 Shadow of Diablo, who's a pretty sweet black/blue coloring.

Comment: That is upsetting, i guess thats true there is a shadow diablo which is pretty neatly colored, thank you for letting me know